# Do duplicate udev rules in different files cause any problems?

Tags: udev

Do exact duplicate udev rules in different files cause any problems?
In my case, it's an 'ADD' rule for a custom device.  The rule is apparently working and I can access the device, but I don't know if there are any side-effects from having the rule show up twice.

Comment: Depends on what it does exactly. It's generally probably fine to execute twice, but why don't you just remove the dupe?

Comment: I want to remove the duplicate, but if there are side effects, there could be existing code that relies upon the side effect.

Comment: Maybe post up the text? If they are exact dupes, I can't imagine how they could be useful. Where did they come from?